# ResponseObserver receiving java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parseUnknownFieldProto3

Tags: google-cloud-speech

In the last couple of days, when I start `StreamingRecognizeRequests`, my `ResponseObserver`'s `onError` method has been receiving errors like the following:

```
[:error #error {
 :cause "com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult.parseUnknownFieldProto3(Lcom/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream;Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet$Builder;Lcom/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite;I)Z"
 :via
 [{:type com.google.api.gax.rpc.CancelledException
   :message "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Failed to read message."
   :at [com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory createException "ApiExceptionFactory.java" 43]}
  {:type io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
   :message "CANCELLED: Failed to read message."
   :at [io.grpc.Status asRuntimeException "Status.java" 526]}
  {:type java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
   :message "com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult.parseUnknownFieldProto3(Lcom/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream;Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet$Builder;Lcom/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite;I)Z"
   :at [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult <init> "StreamingRecognitionResult.java" 73]}]
 :trace
 [[com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult <init> "StreamingRecognitionResult.java" 73]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult <init> "StreamingRecognitionResult.java" 14]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult$1 parsePartialFrom "StreamingRecognitionResult.java" 1098]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionResult$1 parsePartialFrom "StreamingRecognitionResult.java" 1092]
  [com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream readMessage "CodedInputStream.java" 497]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse <init> "StreamingRecognizeResponse.java" 105]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse <init> "StreamingRecognizeResponse.java" 48]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse$1 parsePartialFrom "StreamingRecognizeResponse.java" 1466]
  [com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse$1 parsePartialFrom "StreamingRecognizeResponse.java" 1460]
  [com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser parseFrom "AbstractParser.java" 91]
  [com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser parseFrom "AbstractParser.java" 49]
  [io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2 parseFrom "ProtoLiteUtils.java" 179]
  [io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2 parse "ProtoLiteUtils.java" 171]
  [io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2 parse "ProtoLiteUtils.java" 88]
  [io.grpc.MethodDescriptor parseResponse "MethodDescriptor.java" 266]
  [io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable runInContext "ClientCallImpl.java" 519]
  [io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable run "ContextRunnable.java" 37]
  [io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run "SerializingExecutor.java" 123]
  [java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter call "Executors.java" 511]
  [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask run "FutureTask.java" 266]
  [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask access$201 "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java" 180]
  [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask run "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java" 293]
  [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 1149]
  [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker run "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 624]
  [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java" 748]]}]
```

Forgive the weird formatting. I've been working in Clojure, a language that runs on the JVM, and I've been interacting with the Speech API via the Java client.

So far, I've tried:

- Updating to `[com.google.cloud/google-cloud-speech "0.63.0-beta"]` from the `0.56.0-beta` that is used in the docs.
- Excluding google-cloud-speech's dependency of `io.grpc/grpc-core` and replacing it with `[io.grpc/grpc-all "1.16.0"]` and `[io.grpc/grpc-all "1.15.1"]`
- Using `com.google.cloud.speech.v1` instead of `com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1`.

While my project has been under development and I can't 100% rule out a problem with my code, I've tried reverting to a state that was working before, and get the same issue. It also seems like the kind of error that is less likely to be my code's fault. Happy to post code (which will be in Clojure) if that seems like the source of the problem.

My best guesses are:

- The server's proto definition has changed, or is using some extension that my client isn't aware of, perhaps due to some kind of dependency issue
- Some other dependency issue is causing `[com.google.cloud/google-cloud-speech "0.53.0-beta"]` not to pull in the proper proto dependencies, so it doesn't have this `parseUnknownFieldProto3` method.